# Save wavemon output in a file regularly

Tags: networking, wireless, iwlwifi

I am using "wavemon" WiFi networks monitoring utility. It shows the output on screen. I am interested in the following values:

link quality
signal level
noise level
SNR
Rx rate MCS drop
Tx rate MCS retries failed
channel active
busy

How can I export these values on regular intervals (e.g. 1 second) and append in a CSV file (Each vale in a separate column, i.e. column1= Link quality, column2= Signal Level).

I found the following partial solution, but when I run the command, it says -d is not a valid option.

wavemon -d |grep -i signal >> textfile.txt

Thank you,
Asif

Comment: what does `man wavemon` say about `-d` option?

Comment: It does not eve mention it. So its not valid option. Then how to export the required fields?